# Not able to get session data

Tags: php, magento-1.9, magento2

I am using core session to set data.

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton("core/session", array("name" => "frontend"));
$session->setData("OTP",'12345');
```

In another file i am using

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton("core/session", array("name" => "frontend"));
$session->getData("OTP");
```

but it's showing blank value.

Please help

Comment: for which magneto version you are asking this question?

Answer (score 0):

You can set and get the value in session using :

```
// Set value in session
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setOTP('12345');

// Get value in session
echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getOTP();
```